# For loops python (beginner): Don't know why this won't work

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

So I'm trying to create a program that takes an input such as "34123+74321" and outputs the answer using a for loop. I'm stuck and don't know why my following code won't work:

```
S = str(input())
for char in range(0, len(S)):
    x = S[1:char]
    p = int(char)+1 
    z = S[p:]
    if chr(char) == "+":
        print (int(z)+int(x))
```

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: What goes wrong? Is there an error message?

Comment: Why don't you just split on `+`?

Comment: First look: in the loop first iteration, when char = 0 => S[1:0]

Comment: @juankysmith This gives you a `''`. Shouldn't hurt...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be much easier to do something like this:

```
>>> s = input()
34123+74321
>>> print(sum(int(x) for x in s.split('+')))
108444
```

Broken down:

1. Makes a list of number-strings, by splitting the string into parts with `'+'` as the delimiter.
2. `for` each value in that `list`, converts it to an integer.
3. Find the total or `sum` of those integers.
4. `print` out that value to the screen for the user to see.

You could also try:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = input()
34123+74321
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
108444
```

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant Thank you for your upvote, if it was you. :)

Answer (score 2):

`char` gets assigned the values `(0, 1, ..., len(S)-1)` and therefore `chr(char)` will never be equal to `'+'`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean `if s[char] == "+":`.

In general, you should try to use "speaking" variable names.

E. g., instead of `char`, it would better to use `idx` or something.

```
string = str(input())
for idx in range(0, len(string)):
    if string[idx] == "+":
        part1 = string[1:idx]
        part2 = string[idx+1:]
        print (int(part1) + int(part2))
```

Comment: Cool typo: "cariable".

Comment: @Robᵩ Thx. This is because of the keys on my keyboard which always jump aside when see my finger coming...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a loop to find the position of the '+' character right? Then the code should read:

```
for char in range(len(S)): 
    if S[char] == '+': pos = char
```

Then you can go ahead and take the lengths:

```
z = S[pos+1:]
x = S[:pos]
print int(x) + int(z)
```

However, note that this is not a very *pythonic* way of doing things. In Python, there is a string method `index` which already finds the position you are looking for:

```
pos = '1234+5678'.index('+')
```

An easier way (and more *Pythonic*) of doing this would be:

```
x, z = '1234+5678'.split('+')
```

Of course, you could also do:

```
print sum(map(int, S.split('+')))
```

Which would also work if you have a number of items to add.

If you are starting to learn Python, it would be better if you understand that everything is an object and has its own methods. The more you learn about the methods, the better you will be at Python. It is a higher level program than your traditional languages, so try not to be limited by the same algorithmic structures which you are used to.

Cheers, and happy programming!